# How to override a too long max-age of 6 months on browsers that already cached the site?

Tags: wordpress, apache, caching, http-headers, browser-cache

I've received information from a customer that their website visitors don't get the latest version of their Wordpress website. I tracked it down to browser caching. The max-age is set to 6 months. And this setting is default behaviour by the SiteGround caching plugin. After installing the SG Optimizer caching plugin the below code is added to the htaccess file. This sets the max-age and expiry to a date six months from now. As you can see it also caches html locally. This is the code that gets added to the htaccess:

```
# HTTPS forced by SG-Optimizer
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
# END HTTPS
# Leverage Browser Caching by SG-Optimizer
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive on
    ExpiresDefault                                      "access plus 6 months"
  # CSS
    ExpiresByType text/css                              "access plus 1 year"
  # HTML components (HTCs)
    ExpiresByType text/x-component                      "access plus 2 months"
  # HTML
    ExpiresByType text/html                             "access plus 6 months"
  # JavaScript
    ExpiresByType application/javascript                "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript              "access plus 1 year"
  # Manifest files
    ExpiresByType application/x-web-app-manifest+json   "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/cache-manifest                   "access plus 0 seconds"
  # Media
    ExpiresByType audio/ogg                             "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/gif                             "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/jpg                             "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg                            "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/png                             "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/svg                             "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/svg+xml                         "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType video/mp4                             "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType video/ogg                             "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType video/webm                            "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon                          "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/pdf                       "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash         "access plus 1 year"
  # Web feeds
    ExpiresByType application/atom+xml                  "access plus 1 hour"
    ExpiresByType application/rss+xml                   "access plus 1 hour"
  # Web fonts
    ExpiresByType application/font-woff                 "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/font-woff2                "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject         "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf                "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType font/opentype                         "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>
# END LBC
# GZIP enabled by SG-Optimizer
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    <IfModule mod_filter.c>
       AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE "application/atom+xml" \
          "application/javascript" \
          "application/json" \
          "application/ld+json" \
          "application/manifest+json" \
          "application/rdf+xml" \
          "application/rss+xml" \
          "application/schema+json" \
          "application/vnd.geo+json" \
          "application/vnd.ms-fontobject" \
          "application/x-font-ttf" \
          "application/x-javascript" \
          "application/x-web-app-manifest+json" \
          "application/xhtml+xml" \
          "application/xml" \
          "font/eot" \
          "font/opentype" \
          "image/bmp" \
          "image/svg+xml" \
          "image/vnd.microsoft.icon" \
          "image/x-icon" \
          "text/cache-manifest" \
          "text/css" \
          "text/html" \
          "text/javascript" \
          "text/plain" \
          "text/vcard" \
          "text/vnd.rim.location.xloc" \
          "text/vtt" \
          "text/x-component" \
          "text/x-cross-domain-policy" \
          "text/xml"
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
# END GZIP
```

I've tried fixing it by removing above lines from .htaccess and adding lines like the following:

```
# DISABLE CACHING
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
        ExpiresActive Off
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
        FileETag None
        Header unset ETag
        Header unset Pragma
        Header unset Cache-Control
        Header unset Last-Modified
        Header set Pragma "no-cache"
        Header Set Cache-Control "max-age=0, public, must-revalidate"
        Header Set Expires "Thu, 1 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT"
 </IfModule>
```

But it does not help. It seems the browser just does not make any requests to the server anymore since it has it locally cached an it is serving everything from local cache to the user until the max-age of 6 months are over. Then it will check for a newer version. This problem occurs on all our websites that we host and created for our customers, so this is a big issue for us.

I've already tried changing site url to one without www. Tried to switch the homepage to another page, did not work either. Maybe moving to entire site to a new ip and changing the a-record would work to override local cache?

I'm looking for a clever way to fix this problem. I hope someone knows a solution.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Yah, that is a problem every CDN has run into and invalidating downstream caches is difficult.  There are two possible solutions.

Alter the name of the resource, this can be done automatically with Pagespeed if you have control of the server.  See the [cache extend filter](https://www.modpagespeed.com/doc/filter-cache-extend).

Alternatively, inline the image in the HTML using a [dataurl per RFC 2397](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2397). Easier read is this [post](https://www.bigfastblog.com/embed-base64-encoded-images-inline-in-html) by Phil Whelan.